# Unable to make http request from within Dialogflow inline editor

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am making a chatbot and I need for certain action to make some http request, but for some reason looks billing issue with the account I cant make http calls.

Here is the code:

```
    const actionHandlers = {
         'get.contact': () => {
            var options = {
              host: 'xxx.herokuapp.com',
              port: 443,
              method: 'GET',
              path: '/',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
            };

            http.get('http://xxx.herokuapp.com/', function(res){
                console.log(res);
            });

          if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
            sendGoogleResponse('Hello, Welcome to my Dialogflow agent!'); // Send simple response to user
          } else {
            sendResponse('here should come the result from http request response.'); // Send simple response to user
          }
        } 
    }
```

On the firebase logs I get this message:
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited.

What other option do I have in order for me to call some external http calls without enabling billing? Any work around?

Additional question, can I use any excel parser within the inline editor? I want to parse some excel file, if so, where do I store the excel sheet file? So the idea is that I would like to query from a excel sheet from within Dialogflow Inline Editor.

Comment: You can only make calls to Google-operated endpoints without billing enabled.  There are no workarounds.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple questions, please ask them separately.

Comment: @DougStevenson is Google-operated free of use? Do we have to pay for that? I will make a separate question for the additional question! thanks

Comment: Use of other Google services have may have their own billing.  It's not related to any billing for Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in editor for Dialogflow uses Google's Cloud Functions for Firebase, which have restrictions on the free "Spark" tier. You can upgrade to the "Blaze" tier which lifts these restrictions and requires billing information, but for low levels of usage do not have any charge.

You do not, however, have to use the built-in editor, or even any Google server. You can run your webhook on Heroku directly if you are more familiar with it, for example, or on any other HTTPS server with a valid public IP address. If you are more familiar with another language, Dialogflow provides libraries for other languages as well.